# Internet explorer freezes after few opened web-sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, internet-explorer, websocket

There's something very strange going on with IE11 and websockets.

Simple demo.
Define an explicit proxy in the internet options (on windows), open the IE browser, and browse to https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Then, Check the "Use Secure WebSocket" click 'Connect' & 'Disconnect' 24 times.
You'll notice that after 12 connections (and disconnection) - the connect will take much more time to complete, and after another 12 connection (total of 24 connections) - the IE tab totally freezes. Browsing doesn't work anymore for this specific tab.

Raising the "maximum number of connections per server" in the registry seems to make a difference - so it looks like there's some sort of connection leak inside the browser. http://jwebsocket.org/documentation/reference-guide/internet-explorer-tips

This happens only in internet explorer, and only when working with web sockets VIA proxy.

Anyone has any idea what is the cause for this behavior ? Is there ANY workaround ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Microsoft is well aware of this issue, and it's fixed only in Edge, windows 10. There is no plan currently to fix this in IE 9-11.

Answer (score 0):

[this secury update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3135236) solves the issue.

Comment: This is link only answer.